# How to synchronize non static method variable (object) in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have one method which write to  a file. I need to synchronize file object

```
class MessageFile{

public static final String  fileName="Main.html"
@AutoWired
AppConifg appconfig;

 public boolean writeToFile(String fileContent) throws  Exception{

        String path = appConfig.getNewsPath() + File.separator + fileName; // getNewsPath is non-static method
        final  File alertFile= new File(path);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        synchronized (alertFile) {
          if (!alertFile.exists()) {
              alertFile.createNewFile();
          }
          try {
              out = new FileOutputStream(alertFile, false);
              out.write(fileContent.getBytes());
              out.flush();
          } finally {
              if (out != null) {
                  out.close();
              }
          }
      }
        return true;
    }


    }
```

But above code won`t take lock exclusive lock on file object as another instance of this  class can have lock on this class and write  to file.
So I want  to  how handle this case ?
I found one workaround  creating a temporary file  name appending time stamp (so temporary file name will be always unique) and after writing  content to it , will first delete  original file and then rename temporary file to original file name.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why can't you use an exclusive lock?

Answer (score 0):

You can try synchronizing on MessageFile.class, if it is the only object accessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `File` object (`alertFile`) every time method is run, so the lock does nothing as it is different every time method is run - you need to have static `File` instance shared across all method calls.

If `path` can be different every time the method is run, you could create `static Map<String, File>` instance and use it like this:

1. Get path of the file.
2. If there is no `File` associated with this path, create it.
3. Otherwise, recover existing `File` instance from map.
4. Use this `File` as a lock and do operations on it.

Example based on modified answer:

```
class MessageFile{

    public static final String  fileName="Main.html"
    @AutoWired
    AppConifg appconfig;

    private static final Map<String, File> filesMap = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean writeToFile(String fileContent) throws  Exception{

        String path = appConfig.getNewsPath() + File.separator + fileName; // getNewsPath is non-static method

        final File alertFile;
        synchronized(filesMap) {
            if (filesMap.containsKey(path)) {
                alertFile = filesMap.get(path);
            }
            else {
                alertFile = new File(path);
                filesMap.put(path, alertFile);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        synchronized (alertFile) {
            if (!alertFile.exists()) {
                alertFile.createNewFile();
            }
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(alertFile, false);
                out.write(fileContent.getBytes());
                out.flush();
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Note that the `File` object is based on the result of `getNewsPath` which is individual for every instance.

Comment: "If there is no `File` associated with this path, create it" - in multithreaded context, this would create a race condition. I suggest you add code and show how you solve this.

Comment: Code sample added.

Comment: There are two important issues to mention: 1) this only protects this specific write operation whereas other code still can write to the same file at the same time when not using this method. 2) this protects against two threads writing to the same file at the same time, by letting one thread waiting for the other’s completion, so one thread will still overwrite what the other has written, so it probably doesn’t solve the *actual* problem of having multiple threads trying to write to the same file in the first place…

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not get exclusive lock on file because you are using `synchronized` on a local variable `alertFile` that is not shared between instances of the class `MessageFile` (each object has its own `alertFile`). You have two possibilities to solve this:

1- Create some static object and synchronize on it (you may use `fileName` as it is already there).

2- Having a references in all the objects that point to the same object (passed in the constructor, for example) and synchronize on it.

Comment: Please remember that beginners often don't comprehend the difference between variables and objects.  You said, "you are using `synchronized` on a local variable," but there's nothing wrong with writing `synchronized(foo)` when `foo` is a local variable.  Synchronization doesn't operate on variables:  It operates on _objects_.  The real problem is that the `alertFile` variable refers to an object that is unknown to any other thread.  I know this sounds nit-picky to an experienced developer, but to a beginner, it's the difference between epiphany and utter, hopeless confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize on the class level object ie MessageFile.class or use a static synchronize method wrtietofile() . it will make sure only one thread writes into the file at a time . it also guarantees the lock will be released once the entire data is written to the file by a thread .